# Restrict uploads content view only admin user

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I have created a new website and users are uploading their documents into `wp-uploads/documents/user_name` folder. The url will which these filesa are available  is like this `https://example/wp-content/uploads/documents/example/MP-final.pdf`.

Theses files are public but I want to protect them from public access. I want these files to be viewable and downloadable only for a logged in admin user.

How can achieve that ?

My current Code is following

On htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|zip)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/documents/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

dl-file.php code is followings

```
<?php
/*
 * dl-file.php
 *
 * Protect uploaded files with login.
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/protect-wordpress-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in
 * 
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>
 * @license GPL-3.0+
 * @registry SPDX
 */
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

is_user_logged_in() ||  auth_redirect();
list($basedir) = array_values(array_intersect_key(wp_upload_dir(), array('basedir' => 1)))+array(NULL);
 $basedir_new = $basedir .'/documents';
$file =  rtrim($basedir_new,'/').'/'.str_replace('..', '', isset($_GET[ 'file' ])?$_GET[ 'file' ]:'');

if (!$basedir || !is_file($file)) {
    status_header(404);
    die('404 &#8212; File not found.');
}
$mime = wp_check_filetype($file);
if( false === $mime[ 'type' ] && function_exists( 'mime_content_type' ) )
    $mime[ 'type' ] = mime_content_type( $file );
if( $mime[ 'type' ] )
    $mimetype = $mime[ 'type' ];
else
    $mimetype = 'image/' . substr( $file, strrpos( $file, '.' ) + 1 );
header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype ); // always send this
if ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS' ) )
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file ) );
$last_modified = gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime( $file ) );
$etag = '"' . md5( $last_modified ) . '"';
header( "Last-Modified: $last_modified GMT" );
header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 100000000 ) . ' GMT' );
// Support for Conditional GET
$client_etag = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ? stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) : false;
if( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] ) )
    $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] = false;
$client_last_modified = trim( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] );
// If string is empty, return 0. If not, attempt to parse into a timestamp
$client_modified_timestamp = $client_last_modified ? strtotime( $client_last_modified ) : 0;
// Make a timestamp for our most recent modification...
$modified_timestamp = strtotime($last_modified);
if ( ( $client_last_modified && $client_etag )
    ? ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) && ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    : ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) || ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    ) {
    status_header( 304 );
    exit;
}
// If we made it this far, just serve the file
readfile( $file );
```

Comment: read this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281500/protecting-direct-access-to-pdf-and-zip-unless-user-logged-in-without-plugin

Comment: @Vel that will show files for all logged in user i want restrict that only admin user

Comment: check condition like `is_user_logged_in() and is_admin()`

Comment: on htaccess how we can check that ?

Comment: not in htacces. in php file `dl-file.php`

Comment: getting 404 error not working

Comment: follow this steps https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281500/protecting-direct-access-to-pdf-and-zip-unless-user-logged-in-without-plugin

Comment: same step followed

Comment: do you have this file `dl-file.php` and code?

Comment: Yes i have i will update question with code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205924/discussion-between-sarun-and-vel).